# Seeing and using multiple order books on an asset?

Tags: trade

How can you see/trade on multiple order books in a user friendly UI?

I know StellarX doesn't support this yet. Do stellarTerm or StellarPort support trading on order books where XLM is not the quote currency?

Is there an asset with non-XLM orderbook I can try this with?

Answer (score 1):

StellarPort allows this. Left click the asset and you can either get Info, or select. Select allows you to search for the asset you want.

So if you already know the trading pair is there, you can find it.